# Give a graph model for a permutation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Describe a graph model for solving the following problem: Can the permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be arranged in a sequence so that the adjacent permutations $$p:p_1,\ldots,p_n \text{ and }  q:q_1,\ldots,q_n$$ satisfy $p_i\neq q_i$ for all $i$?

I have problem understanding what the exercise asks. What does "adjacent permutation" mean? Also, in a follow-up question, it says that the statement is true for $n\geq 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a graph whose vertices are the permutations in $S_n$, and two vertices are adjacent whenever the corresponding two permutations $p,q$ satisfy the condition $p(i) \ne q(i), \forall i$.

The problem of finding a sequence of all the permutations in $S_n$ which satisfies the given condition is equivalent to the problem of finding a hamilton path in the graph we just constructed.

Of course, this graph formulation by itself doesn't explain how to construct such a sequence, but it does reformulate the problem in graph-theoretic terms.

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean permutations that are adjacent in the sequence. If the sequence is $\pi_1,\pi_2,\ldots,\pi_{n!}$, then e.g. $\pi_5$ and $\pi_6$ would be adjacent. And where it says "the adjacent permutations" I think they mean "any two adjacent permutations".